# Remove text from string until "-"

Tags: vb.net, substring

I'm trying to extract a text from a string. An example of this built string can be:

> 28/10/2020 21:21:50 Mattia - Stunning Siphonophore - Nautilus Live

I would like to be able to extract just : "Stunning Siphonophore - Nautilus Live"
As you can see, label1.text can contain "-" too, so I'd like to extract everything from the first - until the end.
I am trying with:

```
    Dim str = "28/10/2020 21:21:50 Mattia - Stunning Siphonophore - Nautilus Live"
Dim x = "-"
Dim index = str.IndexOf(x)
If (index >= 0) Then
    str = str.Substring(0, index)
End If
MessageBox.Show(str)
```

but this is doing the exactly opposite of what I want..
Thanks

Comment: The statement "so I'd like to remove everything from the first - until the end" doesn't match the rest of your description. I feel like you're asking for two different things.

Comment: my bad. Updated

Comment: Now you have a confusing reference to `label1.text` in your description.

Comment: right updated..

Comment: Try `str = str.Substring(index)` instead of `str = str.Substring(0, index)`. It'll almost get you to what you need.

Comment: BTW, it's very good that you posted the code that you've tried. It makes it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear if there will always be a space after the `-`, but assuming that it is optional this should work for you:

```
Dim str = "28/10/2020 21:21:50 Mattia - Stunning Siphonophore - Nautilus Live"
Dim x = "-"
Dim index = str.IndexOf(x)
If (index >= 0) Then
    str = str.Substring(index + 1).Trim()
End If
```

Comment: Hi, what if before Mattia I put another - and I still want to extract only "Stunning Siphonophore - Nautilus Live"? Thanks

Comment: Your question specifically said that you wanted from the first one. Are you changing that so you want the last two strings between the `-`?